# What is the difference between rxjava2 and rxkotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

What is the difference between `rxjava2` dependency and `rxkotlin` dependency.
 If I'm using `rxkotlin` dependency, should i need to add `rxjava2` dependency along with that.

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:x.y.z'
// do i need to add the below dependencies also?
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.4'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> the thing is RX stands for Reactive Extensions , and Rx Java ,
>   Rx Kotlin or Rx Swift all are the implementation of Reactive
>   Extensions in that particular language.

**What is RxJAVA?**
RxJava is a Java VM implementation of Reactive Extensions. where we can create asynchronous data stream on any thread, transform it and these asynchronous data streams can be consumed by Observers on any thread.

**What is RxKotlin?**
RxKotlin is a Kotlin implementation of Reactive Extensions.

**What is RxAndroid?**
It is specific to Android Platform with some more added classes on top of RxJava.

for more details , visit my collection of rxjava simple examples  https://github.com/myJarvis/Intro_to_RxJava .

and to more clarify , RxKotlin has some convenient extension functions  which comes with Kotlin.

You can either use {RxJava & RxAndroid}  or {RxKotlin}

> You can use RxJava with Kotlin out-of-the-box

Comment: Ok, then do i need to add both rxjava2 along with rxkotlin @Thunder

Comment: see , the thing is RX stands for Reactive Extensions , and Rx Java , Rx Kotlin or Rx Swift all are the implementation of Reactive Extensions in that particular lang

Comment: yes you need to add these both (if you are working on android project)
 implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:${rxAndroid}"
 implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:${rxJava}"

Comment: you can visit https://github.com/myJarvis/Intro_to_RxJava . , you will get a basic understanding of how to start working with these two.

Comment: Can you take a look at the answer given by akshay_shahane

Comment: @ManojPerumarath mate i am using rxjava in our android app which is used by 2.5million :)  whole code base is writtern in rxjava and kotlin

Comment: you can start coding after adding these two dependencies ,  implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:${rxAndroid}" implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:${rxJava}".
for code example visit here 
https://github.com/myJarvis/Intro_to_RxJava.

Comment: i added some basic examples here , how u can use Observables and observer and all other rxjava stuff

Comment: Ok i'll a take look into that

Comment: "Schedulers are introduced in RxAndroid" No they aren't. http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Scheduler.html RxAndroid only provides some scheduler _implementations_.

Answer (score 6):

Since Kotlin is 100% interoperable with Java, you can use most Java libraries in your Kotlin projects without any difficulties—and the RxJava library is no exception.

There is a dedicated [RxKotlin library](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin), which is a Kotlin wrapper around the regular RxJava library. This wrapper provides extensions that optimize RxJava for the Kotlin environment and can further reduce the amount of boilerplate code you need to write.

If you are using `rxkotlin` you just need to add the following line

```
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxkotlin:x.y.z'
```

and if you want to use `rxjava2` you need to include the other dependencies i.e

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.4'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
```

but if you are using Kotlin as your programming language I will recommend you using `rxkotlin`

More detail refer to [this link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/kotlin-reactive-programming-with-rxjava-and-rxkotlin--cms-31577)

Comment: I understood that, but this doesn't answer my question

Comment: see you can use RxJava with Kotlin out-of-the-box , no need to use rxkotlin if you are using rxjava , that is also fine , when you will write code , extension function will be available bcs you are already using kotin with rxjava

Comment: your answer itself says this  RxKotlin library, which is a Kotlin wrapper around the regular RxJava library .

Comment: You don't need to add `rxjava` exactly because `rxkotlin` is a wrapper around `rxjava` and will bring it in automatically.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxkotlin/2.3.0, `rxkotlin` depends on `rxjava`. So it's automatically added as a [transitive dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_terminology.html#sub:terminology_transitive_dependency) unless you specifically exclude it.

Unsurprisingly, `rxkotlin` does *not* depend on `rxandroid` so you do need to add that if you want to use it. Both `rxandroid` and `rxkotlin` use the same `rxjava` types, so they can interoperate freely.

Answer (score 0):

The predominant library in this Android development is **RxJava**. Since **Kotlin** is fully interoperable with Java libraries, **RxKotlin** is only a thin wrapper over the original **RxJava**.